# Side by side nav still doesnt work properly plus other issues

Tags: html, css

The sidebyside nav now displays something but shortens the original menu-text to only text-length (it should take the whole line). The links in the top line should be displayed next to each other but w/o boxes. I've tried everything w/o success. I want to do my code with as little scripting as possible, only HTML and CSS if possible.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: xxx-large;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h4 {
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f00000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  <!-- width: 20%;
  -->position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f00000;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 1 em 2 em;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: medium;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
  background-color: #00a000;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

#elf {
  background-color: #0000c0;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#elf:hover {
  background-color: #0000e0;
  color: #c0c0c0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#divine {
  background-color: #a000a0;
  color: #c0c000;
  font-weight: bold;
  width;
  100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

#divine:hover {
  background-color: #c000c0;
  color: #f0f000;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000f0;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.divine-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.divine:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.divine:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.divine-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000f0;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.divine-content+a {
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.size {
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

#divine-content+a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

#divine:hover+.divine-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

#divine:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<h1>Thyra Kristin Lang<br></h1>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- </div>    -->

<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="menu" background-color="005000">

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

      <h4>Hauptmenü</h4>
      <table class="size">
        <tr>
          <td><a style="text-size:normal padding-right: 2 em" onclick="javascript:normal()" border="0">A&nbsp;</a>
            <td><a style="text-size:large padding-right: 2 em  border-style: none;" onclick="javascript:large()">A</a></td>
            <td><a style="text-size:x-large padding-right: 2 em" onclick="javascript:xlarge()">A</a></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
      <div><a href="vita.html" target="main">Lebenslauf</a></div>
      <div><a href="werke.html" target="main">Werkeverzeichnis</a></div>
      <div class="dropdown"><a href="#" name="divine" id="divine">Divine</a>
        <div class="divine-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" name="elf" id="elf">Elfenblut</a>
      <a href="#" name="poetry" id="poetry">Gedichte</a>
      <br>
    </div>

  </div>

  <iframe id="main" name="main" src="willkommen.html" background-color="005000">blub</iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: You mean the dropdown should open horizontally?

Comment: I've added your code into a runnable snippet and corrected a missing quote `"` in HTML.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:inline-block` it will make all elements displayed on a block and use margin or padding to separate them.

Comment: You should copy the snippet from the question and make modifications to demonstrate your solution. It's not particularly clear.

Comment: I don't know which one of them is the The sidebyside nav he talked about

Comment: I agree the question is vague. That doesn't warrant vague answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple things: Only one element should have an specific value for `id`. The `id` is unique per element. Styling element inline and externally can sometimes make it difficult to troubleshoot a problem. My personal preference is one or the other except in certain cases.

The question may need more details. Here's what I think you want using flex I was able to position the links next to each other and the take up the whole line without boxes.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
font-size: xxx-large; text-align: center; text-decoration: underline; }

h4 {
font-size: large; text-align: center; text-decoration: underline; background-color: cyan;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f00000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  <!-- width: 20%;    -->
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


#mySidenav1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f00000;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 1 em 2 em;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: medium;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

 /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: visible;
}

.menu {
background-color: #a0a0a0; width: 20%; height: 100%; float:left; overflow:hidden;
}

#main {
background-color: #00a000; width: 80%; height: 100%; float:left; overflow:hidden; border: none;
}


#elf {
font-weight: bold;
}

#elf:hover {

background-color: #0000e0;
color: #c0c0c0;
font-weight: bold;

}

#divine {
font-weight: bold;
}


#divine:hover {

background-color: #c000c0;
color: #f0f000;
font-weight: bold;
}





/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000f0;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}



/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.divine-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.divine:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.divine:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}



.divine-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000f0;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}


.divine-content + a {
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.size {
   display: inline;
   color: black;
   background-color: red;
   text-align: center;



}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
#divine-content + a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
#divine:hover + .divine-content {
display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
#divine:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<h1>Thyra Kristin Lang<br></h1>
<div id="mySidenav1" class="sidenav1">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">x</a>
  <a href="vita.html" target="main">Lebenslauf</a>
  <a href="werke.html" target="main">Werkeverzeichnis</a>
  <a href="#" name="divine" id="divine">Divine</a>
  <a href="#" name="elf" id="elf">Elfenblut</a>
  <a href="#" name="poetry" id="poetry">Gedichte</a>
  <br>
</div>
<br>
<!-- <h2>Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p> -->
<!-- <span id="MyButton" style="font-size:medium; cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">Hauptmenü öffnen</span>  -->

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- </div>    -->

<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="menu" background-color="005000">

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

      <h4>Hauptmenü</h4>
      <table class="size">
        <tr>
          <td><a style="text-size:normal padding-right: 2 em" onclick="javascript:normal()" border="0">A&nbsp;</a></td>

          <td><a style="text-size:large padding-right: 2 em  border-style: none;" onclick="javascript:large()">A</a></td>

          <td><a style="text-size:x-large padding-right: 2 em" onclick="javascript:xlarge()">A</a></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
      <div><a href="vita.html" target="main">Lebenslauf</a></div>
      <div><a href="werke.html" target="main">Werkeverzeichnis</a></div>
      <div class="dropdown"><a href="#" name="divine" id="divine">Divine</a>
        <div class="divine-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" name="elf" id="elf">Elfenblut</a>
      <a href="#" name="poetry" id="poetry">Gedichte</a>
      <br>
    </div>

  </div>

  <iframe id="main" name="main" src="willkommen.html" background-color="005000">blub</iframe>

</div>
```